# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in my Activity using Google API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a test a program for my University which uses Google maps following a tutorial. I made everything like in tutorial, but my app crashes before even showing anything with message "Unfortunately SocialFoot has stopped". I tried to debug and it seems like it crashes even before entering to onCreate method. This is my code:

```
package it.univpm.dii.socialfoot;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockMapActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SocialFootActivity extends SherlockMapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
  05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{it.univpm.dii.socialfoot/it.univpm.dii.socialfoot.activities.SocialFootActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.univpm.dii.socialfoot.activities.SocialFootActivity
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.univpm.dii.socialfoot.activities.SocialFootActivity
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-18 19:29:59.343: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.univpm.dii.socialfoot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SocialFootActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Layout:

Comment: `SherlockMapActivity extends MapActivity` ?

Comment: Give the same error. SherlockMapActivity is a library that extends the native MapActivity http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: clean your project ..and you have `it.univpm.dii.socialfoot.activities.SocialFootActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs indicate the app is trying to launch `it.univpm.dii.socialfoot.activities.SocialFootActivity`, but `SocialFootActivity` is in package `it.univpm.dii.socialfoot`. If this is happening at the start of your application (since that activity is set as the launch activity), I would try cleaning and rebuilding your project and trying again.